# How to get output of gcloud composer command?

Tags: gcloud, airflow

I'm executing gcloud composer commands:

```
gcloud composer environments run airflow-composer \ 
--location europe-west1 --user-output-enabled=true \
backfill -- -s 20171201 -e 20171208 dags.my_dag_name \ 
kubeconfig entry generated for europe-west1-airflow-compos-007-gke.
```

It's a regular [airflow backfill](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill). The command above is printing the results at the end of the whole backfill range, is there any way to get the output in a streaming manner ? Each time a DAG gets backfilled it will be printed in the standard output, like in a regular airflow-cli.

Comment: Hi any update for situation? I have faced same similar situation.And how about reset_dagruns parameter?Normally this parameter works on airflow cli but dont work on gcloud composer.

Comment: You can connect to the docker container and run the command directly

Comment: Thank you for good solution.It works for me.